# Why MSDN mentions to override the Finalize() method?

Tags: c#, msdn, finalize

Since my first lessons about C# classes I've learned that not only I cannot invoke the `Finalize()` method of a class explicitly(it is called by the Garbage Collector), but I'm not even allowed to implement it in my custom classes.
The thing that makes me a bit confused is that in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddae83kx.aspx) like here -

`By default, the Object.Finalize method does nothing. If you want the garbage collector to perform cleanup operations on your object before it reclaims the object's memory, you must override this method in your class.`

I've found numerous places that suggest something else. Can anyone clarify why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same MSDN page you can read:

> **You cannot override the Finalize method in the C#** or C++ programming languages. **In C#, use destructor syntax** to implement the Finalize method. In version 2.0 of the .NET Framework, C++ provides its own syntax for implementing the Finalize method, as described in Destructors and Finalizers in Visual C++. In earlier versions, C++ used destructor syntax for the Finalize method, as C# does.

It means that the `Finalize()` method is what will be called by the Garbage Collector but it's hidden by the *friendly* syntax of destructors. What you'll write as `ClassName.~ClassName()` will be rewritten as `ClassName.Finalize()` by the compiler.

**EDIT**
To make the point clear this is the actual syntax to implement the finalizer in C#:

```
class MyClass
{
    ~MyClass()
    {
    }
}
```

Usually you do not even need to implement your finalizer method (and it can even hurts performance) but you'll implement the [Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx).

Comment: OK, now that makes me a bit stupid too. I've got the point - the documentation is not C#-specific. But can you really use the `ClassName.~ClassName()` syntax? I think not.

Comment: You'll write `class Foo { public ~Foo() { ... }}` and I guess you cannot call it directly in any way. Not using that syntax, at least.

Comment: @Nero I wrote ClassName.~ClassName() only to full qualify the method name, it's not something you'll write (as you can't write ClassName.Finalize()).

Comment: @Adriano: I did get the fully qualifying thing. But can you call the destructor in your with any kind of syntax? Isn't it supposed to be called automatically with either of garbage collection, `using` syntax or application-domain exit.

Comment: @Nero yes, you can't call it directly. It'll be called always by the GC, "using" will just call the Dispose() method.